# 3D850 stuck in the nozzle

Tags: filament, pla, nozzle

I am trying to use a 3D850 PLA filament which is supposed to work without any issues with any PLA printer. As a printer, I use Dagoma NEVA which is supposed to work with any PLA filament. I can print with the filament without any issue, but I encounter a problem when I need to swap the filament. Somehow 3D850 sticks within the nozzle and even when it's heated I have to push really hard with another filament to push the current filament out (usually when the nozzle is heated up I can just easily push a filament inside for it to come out of the nozzle).

Is there any special behavior of 3D850 that may cause it to stick inside of the nozzle?

Comment: Consider overheating the head to further decrease the viscosity of the residual material in the nozzle.  Then, of course, return to design temperature before printing.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the max temperature for Neva is 220º C (according to https://3dprinting.com/pricewatch/3d-printer/dagoma-neva/) and this is what their "nozzle cleaning mode" uses. I am wondering in general if I'm doing something wrong because print temperature for 3D850 is 190-230ºC and I printed it at 210º. I can try printing it on 220º but I don't understand why I cant remove the filament easily.  So far my other experience was only with Verbatim PLA. The recommendation for it is 200-220º and it perfectly worked at 210º

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that  particular brand of PLA is changing state inside the nozzle as it cools. Quoting from the manufacturer's page,

> Materio3D PLA uses the NatureWorks Ingeo 3D850 polymer, specially
>   engineered for 3D printing. It is tougher and stronger than standard
>   PLA and can be annealed for improved heat resistance and toughness!

If the residual material in the nozzle cools slowly enough (at the end of a print) to anneal, then by design it won't re-melt at the same temperature as the raw filament material.   I would recommend changing your gcode so that the extruder hotend is held at temperature after a print completes, and making sure to clear the nozzle with an alternate type of filament before allowing the nozzle to cool.

quoting from [another page](https://www.pushplastic.com/products/premium-pla),

> To achieve a heat treat on a printed part, submerge in water (or bake
>   in oven) at 200F for up to 30 minutes.

notice that's Fahrenheit, well below extruder temperatures.

Comment: I'm totally fascinated by this explanation, +1, but it has to be noted that all PLA can be annealed, so *to a certain degree*, all filaments should manifest this behaviour. Also: holding the hotend hot indefinitively without extruding is likely to cause clogging the first time you forget about it, I would suggest instead that the OP use `G4` or equivalent code to delay the shutdown of an amount of time sufficient to purge the nozzle.

Comment: @mac  I suspect all PLAs do show this -- Whenever I restart, and do a "push-through," the initial glob is definitely stiffer to push out than when I'm feeding fresh filament by hand.

Comment: Annealing affects the structure, and maybe the behaviour around the glass transition, not so much the fluid transition. There could still be some baking/polymerisation or loss of solvent though.